# Prism - Cross Region DataBinding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, prism

Lets say i have 2 regions A and B.

Region A:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="tba"> HAHAHA </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Region B:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=tba, Path=Text}"/>
</Grid>
```

This does not work. What is the workaround to fix this, so in region B also "HAHAHA" is displayed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view models can communicate with each other to make the connection via `EventAggregator`.

```
// needs to be public if the two view models live in different assemblies
internal class ThePropertyChangedEvent : PubSubEvent<string>
{
}

internal class ViewAViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ViewAViewModel( IEventAggregator eventAggregator )
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<ThePropertyChangedEvent>().Subscribe( x => TheProperty = x );
    }

    public string TheProperty
    {
        get { return _theProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _theProperty)
                return;
            _theProperty = value;
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ThePropertyChangedEvent>().Publish( _theProperty );
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    #region private
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    private string _theProperty;
    #endregion
}
```

... `ViewBViewModel` is essentially the same thing (in this simple example).

Comment: is there perhaps an only-XAML solution ?

Comment: There might be one, if you traverse the visual tree long enough, but it will be rather complicated and fragile. And I can not see a benefit, really, because if you want to bind text block b to text block a's text, you expect that to change, so it should be bound to a property in the view model anyway.

Comment: Yes this is the solution that has helped me, had made an event communicate link between multiple modules and main Shell and all is working fine.