# How to access text from a TextBox from one view and display it in a TextBlock on another view in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I have a view in wpf, that has a range of different boxes, for example, First/Last Name (TextBox), Date of Birth (DatePickers), Marital Status (ComboBox) etc.

What I want to be able to do, is get the text entered into the TextBoxes and show them in a TextBlock on a seperate view.

I have added properties for all the corresponding items in there retrospective ViewModels, but from there on in, I'm unsure on how to implement this any further.

Other questions I have looked at aren't very clear or easy to follow.

Comment: Mediator pattern.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prism - Cross Region DataBinding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767926/prism-cross-region-databinding)

Comment: Or not a possible duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to set the DataContext of both views to the same instance of your ViewModel.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Local.EditableView DataContext={Binding Person} />
    <Local.ReadOnlyView DataContext={Binding Person} />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. I assuming you are not using any framework like Caliburn.Micro.

Simple Approach:

1. Create a global static class that shares information across multiple ViewModel.
2. Now, from the first ViewModel, update the static class property using the ViewModel property setter, something like

> ```
> private string _lastName;
> public string LastName{
>   get{
>       return _lastName
>   }
>   set{
>       _lastName = value;
>       SharedClass.LastName = value;
>   }
> }
> ```

3. Now access this shared class from the other ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a [Mediator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) to communicate between view models.

You would typically register a "target" view model -- "colleague" -- with the mediator for certain operations that the view model is interested in and provide a callback action for what is supposed to happen when that operation occurs.  Then the other view model -- the one performing the operation that the target is interested in -- would notify the mediator when the operation happens, and the mediator would then perform the associated action on all the colleagues that are registered for that operation.

Here's an example of a mediator:

```
static class Mediator
{
    private static Dictionary<string, List<Action<Object>>> _tokenCallbacks 
        = new Dictionary<string, List<Action<object>>>();

    internal static void Register(string token, Action<Object> callback)
    {
        token = token.ToLower();

        if (_tokenCallbacks.ContainsKey(token))
        {
            var l = _tokenCallbacks[token];
            var found = false;

            foreach (var existingCallback in l)
            {
                if (existingCallback.Equals(callback))
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!found) l.Add(callback);
        }
        else
        {
            var l = new List<Action<Object>>(new[] { callback });
            _tokenCallbacks.Add(token, l);
        }
    }

    internal static void NotifyColleagues(string callbackToken, Object args)
    {
        callbackToken = callbackToken.ToLower();

        if (_tokenCallbacks.ContainsKey(callbackToken)) 
            _tokenCallbacks[callbackToken].ForEach((x) => x(args));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those views and their view models should reference a shared model of the data.

So that when data is entered in one view, its view model updates the model and the model update triggers a update in the other view model and finally in the other view.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of cross viewmodel communication, use Messenger. That acts as a mediator and simplified lots of issues like this. You can either implement one yourself or use either the MVVM light or Prism toolkits.